# Expectation of a conditional density

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to figure out why the following equation holds: 
$$f_{Y}(y) = E(f_{Y|X}(y|X))$$

I have sort of "worked out" the RHS to be: 
\begin{align}
f_{Y}(y) &= E(f_{Y|X}(y|X))  \\[5pt]
         &= \int \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{X}(x)} f_{X}(x) dx  \\[5pt]
         &= \int f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx  \\[5pt]
         &= f_{Y}(y)
\end{align}

Is this approach correct? If so, why do integrate with respect to $f_{X}(x)dx$ ?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Yes it is. I have made the required changes.

Comment: apart from $y$ that's the only other variable. To be more accurate the book should have stated $E_x(\cdot)$.

Comment: Do you know how to obtain the expected value of $g(X) $ where $g $ is a function.  $f_{Y|X}(y|X) $ is just another function of $X $ since, in effect, you are holding $y $ fixed.

Comment: Thanks all very much for your replies. @ZacharyBlumenfeld I thought about your input and I think it made a lot of sense. Since $X$ is left as a RV on the RHS, it is indeed a function of $X$. And we include the $f_{X}(x)$ as per the definition of $E(g(X))$, solving for which we get the LHS.

Comment: @Sachin_ruk "To be more accurate the book should have stated Ex(⋅)" Well, certainly not, actually this habit of adding random variables as indexes to expectation signs is quite superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

To close this one:

$f_{Y|X}(y|X)$ is a function of the random variable $X$. When we write $E(f_{Y|X}(y|X))$ it is understood that the expected value is taken with respect to all "sources of randomness" present. In our case the only source of randomness is $X$, so translating $E$ to an integral we have

$$ E[f_{Y|X}(y|X)] =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{Y|X}(y|X) f_{X}(x) dx$$

Using Baye's law for densities we also have

$$f_{Y|X}(y|X) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{X}(x)}$$

and inserting into the expected value expression and simplifying we get

$$E[f_{Y|X}(y|X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx$$

Integrating out $X$ from the joint density, leads in turn to $f_{Y}(y)$, as we are asked to show, because

$$f_Y(y) = \frac {d}{dy} \text {lim}_{x \to \infty} F_{X,Y}(x, y)$$

where $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the joint distribution function,

$$f_Y(y) = \frac {d}{dy} \text {lim}_{x \to \infty} \int^y_{-\infty} \int_{-\infty}^x f_{X,Y}(s, t)ds\,dt$$

$$ = \frac {d}{dy}  \int^y_{-\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x, t)dx\,dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x, y)dx$$